# Transaction boundary of spring integration splitter

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-integration

The base question is actually very simple, lets consider the following chain:

```
<int:poller id="inputPoller" task-executor="inputTaskPool" fixed-delay="${input.poller.interval}"
            receive-timeout="${input.poller.timeout}" max-messages-per-poll="${poller.messages}">
    <int:transactional transaction-manager="chainedTransactionManager"/>
</int:poller>

<int:chain id="someInputChain" input-channel="theInputChannel">
    <int:poller ref="inputPoller" />
    <!-- various transfomers, nothing asynchronous -->
    <int:splitter id="messageSplitter" ref="messageSplitterService" apply-sequence="false" />
    <int:transformer id="messagePersister" ref="messagePersisterService" method="persistMessageMetadata" />
</int:chain>
```

Will all messages generated by the `messageSplitter` be in the same transaction and in the same thread or can it be that they are subsequently handled in different transactions/from different threads?

The splitter calls (synchronously) a REST service that will give it the list of destination channels a message has to go. It will then create so many copies and set a header to the output channel. That list is returned from the splitter. The `messagePersister` will store the key of the new messages in a database table together with some metadata.

Is each call of `messagePersisterService.persistMessageMetadata` (for each splitted message) in the same transaction/thread as the original message or will they be handled each in their own transaction?

Comment: You have already asked such a question and I have given you some answer.

Comment: No, it is a different question. The context is the same but the question is different. I gladly remove the context so that it no longer seems like a duplicate. I assumed more information can only be helpful :)

Comment: @ArtemBilan There you go, context removed, its now about the transaction boundaries of the splitter without going into details why im interested in knowing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Spring Integration nothing goes to a new thread, unless you say that explicitly.
Since you have a `<int:splitter>` withing `<chain>`, it is really going to produce splitted items one by one to the next handler in the chain. Everything happens on the same thread in the task initiated by the `<poller>` and, in your case, within TX.